# ROS Answers SE migration: ODE in gazebo

Tags: ros, physics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is ODE physics engine in gazebo, where is it used exactly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29624/ode-in-gazebo/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ODE is used for the building newer environments and the physics (viz. collision detections) of the simulation, have a look here; [http://www.d.umn.edu/~cprince/PubRes/Gazebo/index.php?page=part5](http://www.d.umn.edu/%7Ecprince/PubRes/Gazebo/index.php?page=part5)

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0